# Hiding values next to seaborn colormap

Tags: python, seaborn, colorbar, kdeplot

[image: Plot I'm getting right now]

Here's a picture of the plot I get for a bivariate density. However the numbers next to the colorbar are really not of much use here, and I would like either to delete them or replace by 'LOW' and 'HIGH'.
I didn't find any way of doing this so if any of you has info, it would be great.
Here's the code i used for creation of this plot :

```
            df = self.dfuinsights
            ax = sns.kdeplot(data = df, x = key1, y = key2, fill = True, alpha = 0.7, tresh = tsh, levels = lvls, cmap = "viridis")
            xlabel = self.colnamesMapper_uinsights[key1]
            ylabel = self.colnamesMapper_uinsights[key2]
            title = "Bivariate Densities : " + xlabel + " - " + ylabel
            self.__convert_capitals(ax, title, xlabel, ylabel) #just modifying titles and xlabel, ignore this)
            plt.show()
            plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html?highlight=kdeplot#seaborn.kdeplot) can take arguments to be passed to [the colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) in `cbar_kws=`. To remove the ticks+labels, you can request an empty list of ticks:

```py
geyser = sns.load_dataset("geyser")
sns.kdeplot(
    data=geyser, x="waiting", y="duration",
    fill=True, thresh=0, levels=100, cmap="viridis",
    cbar=True, cbar_kws=dict(ticks=[])
)
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you capture the return value from `kdeplot()`, you should be able to get a reference to the colorbar axes, and then you can use any of [the functions provided by `Axes` to modify ticks and ticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels)

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(
    data=geyser, x="waiting", y="duration",
    fill=True, thresh=0, levels=100, cmap="viridis",
    cbar=True
)
cax = ax.figure.axes[-1]  # This assume there are no other axes in the figure
cax.set_yticklabels([])
```